# vscode is not remebering MRU's?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is required to make the Most Recently Used files work?  For some reason VSCode is not saving MRU's anymore.  I'm using the latest version in Windows 10 and nothing gets saved anymore.  I did disable a bunch of plugins related to java recently but that should not matter.  Anyone have a clue what I can check to get MRU's back?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have noticed that as of the last few months (not sure exactly when it started), the "jump list" for Visual Studio 2019 on the Windows 10 task bar does not stay up-to-date. However: rebooting the system causes the list to update; and, the MRU lists as displayed in VS are correct, with the most recent files/projects/etc. Please provide more specifics in your question, including what exact version of VS Code you're using, what MRU lists you're asking about, and whether the updating is simply delayed or just doesn't work at all.

Comment: There is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84421) related to recently used in VS code 1.40. What version are you on? Does it repo in the current VS Code insiders build?

Comment: I'm using vscode 1.40.1.  I run vscode and simply open a file and close it.  then even restart vscode.  I goto file menu -> open recent and I don't see it in the list.  I see other files but shouldn't it be clearing old entries if all slots are used up?